# What is the lens diagram of this Pentacon 50mm F1.8 multi coating lens?

Tags: lens-design, old-lenses

I'm trying to find detailed lens diagrams (showing the lens elements) of this old prime lens I have but I can't seem to find anything. Does anyone know where could I find it?

Here are some photos of the lens:

[image: photo of the lens front]

[image: photo of the lens's rings]

Comment: You could improve its performance by taking that UV filter off ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's of a double gauss design...

[image]

Comment: Where could I find the table with its information like radius, glass and other stuff?

Comment: @metopop6, I don't believe I've ever seen those specifics given for any lens... not even in a patent application.

Comment: @metapop6, service manuals for camera gear are nearly impossible to find/get your hands on. Something like [a youtube teardown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=I-06BGrA6Bo) might be closest you can get.

Comment: @StevenKersting I wonder could you indicate where you sourced this diagram?

Comment: @osullic, there's a few sources for Pentacon/Praktica information; but this came from camera-wiki.org: http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Pentacon_auto_1.8/50